# React - Hide parent's child element on blur event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, tailwind-css

I'm working on a custom input component. so when user clicks on the input element I want to show a dropdown that will contain default ten records and if user types some keyword in the input the dropdown will be updated with the results matching the keyword.

when user clicks on the input I want to show the dropdown and If they click out the container I want to hide the dropdown.

so I've added an `onBlur` event to the container and now if I click somewhere else it hides the dropdown but If I try to select a record It's also hidding the dropdown which is incorrect.

How can I hide the dropdown when the clicks outside of the input container? any suggestions?

```
export const ListBoxInput = ({ label, data, keyName }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({ key: null, value: null });
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className='flex items-center space-x-3'
      onBlur={() => setShowDropdown(false)}
    >
      <label className='block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700'>{label}</label>

      <div className='relative group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={selected.key}
          onFocus={() => setShowDropdown(true)}
          onChange={(e) => setSelected({ key: e.target.value, value: null })}
          disabled={!data.length}
          placeholder={!data.length ? 'No data...' : ''}
          className='w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 mt-1 text-left bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm disabled:opacity-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-brand focus:border-brand sm:text-sm'
        />

        {showDropdown && (
          <div className='absolute z-10 w-full py-1 mt-3 overflow-auto text-base bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-56 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none '>
            {data.map((r) => (
              <button
                key={r.id}
                type='button'
                onClick={() => {
                  setSelected({ key: r[keyName], value: r.id });
                  setShowDropdown(false);
                }}
                className='block w-full py-2 pl-3 text-left hover:bg-gray-100 pr-9'
              >
                {r[keyName]}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Don't use `onBlur`. You can use a hook like [useClickOutside](https://github.com/teetotum/react-attached-properties/blob/master/examples/useClickOutside.js).

Comment: thanks will check it out!